# JS/jQuery code flow - combine an animation with a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a page that has a simple div when the pointer is outside of it, which fades in to a different div, with different content, on hover.

I want the simple div to not be a link, but the different div to be a link (the entire div).

The following jsfiddle describes and demonstrates the issue that I'm having:
http://jsfiddle.net/neigere/3sP3N/

You can see the bug live here:
http://tedneiger.com

It seems like a code sequence execution issue that could be fixed by moving where I call the click function, but I've attempted several variations and haven't been able to successfully resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the click is caught by the `professional` div, and does not reach the `professional-detail` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/3sP3N/46/

In this fiddle, I hide the `professional` div after it's fully gone. It seems to work well now. I needed to set `position` to `absolute`, because without it, somewhy the detailed div also disappeared. I found a `margin-top:`... in the css for the mousein class, I didn't understand why, and I removed it.

Comment: I don't know if you have read it, but I see you are new, so I link it... http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask